# PHPSpec: Issue stubbing out PDO::execute

Tags: php, pdo, bdd, phpspec

I'm having an issue stubbing out PDO::execute using PHPSpec and prophecy, but I keep getting an error that:

```
29  ! it should perform PDO queries
  method `Double\PDO\P3::execute()` is not defined.

   0 vendor/phpspec/prophecy/src/Prophecy/Prophecy/MethodProphecy.php:48
     throw new Prophecy\Exception\Doubler\MethodNotFoundException("Method `Double\PDO\P3::ex"...)
   1 vendor/phpspec/prophecy/src/Prophecy/Prophecy/ObjectProphecy.php:242
     Prophecy\Prophecy\MethodProphecy->__construct([obj:Prophecy\Prophecy\ObjectProphecy], "execute", [obj:Prophecy\Argument\ArgumentsWildcard])
   2 [internal]
     Prophecy\Prophecy\ObjectProphecy->__call("execute", [array:1])
   3 [internal]
     spec\Devtools\MysqlModelSpec->it_should_perform_PDO_queries([obj:PhpSpec\Wrapper\Collaborator])
```

Here's my spec:

```
class MysqlModelSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(\PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($connection);
    }

    function it_should_perform_PDO_queries(\PDO $connection)
    {
        $connection->prepare(
            "SELECT :key FROM :collection WHERE :where"
        )->willReturn(true);

        $connection->execute(
            array(
                'key' => 'user_name',
                'collection' => 'users',
                'where' => 'userid=1'
            )
        )->willReturn(true);

        $this->get('user_name', 'users', 'userid=1')
            ->shouldReturn(
                array('user_name' => 'seagoj')
            );
    }
}
```

I know Prophecy doesn't stub out any methods that don't exist, but PDO is baked into PHP and the PDO::prepare stub works fine. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You can't do this `"SELECT :key FROM :collection WHERE :where"` - On top of that, even if you could, you're using a MySQL reserved word, being [`key`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: *However,* you can do `"SELECT $var1 FROM $var2 WHERE $var3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's all just calling PDO under the hood, then it's not using PDO properly.

The core PDO object has no `execute()` method. That's purely for prepared statements, which is what `->prepare()` returns. There **IS** `->exec()` for immediate execution of queries, but that doesn't support prepared statements.

The basic sequence would be

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('...');
$stmt->execute(...);
```

Comment: Ah, that's likely it. I'm calling it on the wrong object.

Comment: Is there something I don't know about `"SELECT :key FROM :collection WHERE :where"`?

Comment: I posted a comment to that effect under OP's question, plus is using `key`. I thought that the OP's framework could handle this.

Comment: `key` might be a reserved word, but `:key` isn't. it's just a parameter. `select key from` would fail, `select :key from` wouldn't, because that `:` makes all the difference.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was *just saying*, as per [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411164/phpspec-issue-stubbing-out-pdoexecute#comment39638365_25411164) *"On top of that, even if you could..."* ;-) still, can't bind tables and/or columns.

Comment: Thanks for the notes on the bindings, but I'll just adjust for it in my wrapper function.

Comment: Unless you're implementing some kind of "meta-placeholder" that your stuff will replace, you'll still get failures. PDO placeholders can only represent VALUES in a query,. never field/table names or other sql keywords.

Comment: Right, I'll swap the field and table names prior to sending it to prepare.